# How we create sink(5) variable in tcl script

Tags: tcl, ns2

i am using 20 node in ns2 , i am trying to access the  a(0)  a(1) a(2) a(3) a(4) variables with for loop how can i do that

here is my  code

```
for {set i 0} {$i < $val(nn)} {incr i} {
    set sink($i) [new Agent/LossMonitor]
    $ns attach-agent $n($i) $sink($i)

}
```

but its gives an error
    bad variable name "sink(0)": upvar won't create a scalar variable that looks like an array element

i declare the variable in following manner

```
proc record {} {
  global sink(0) sink(1) sink(2) sink(3) sink(4) sink(5)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use

```
global sink
```

(global is just a special `upvar` case)

variables that end with `(...)` are (associative) arrays, using numbers as key is not recommended, it is better to use a list instead, e.g.

```
set mylist {}
# append some elements
lappend mylist "foo" "bar" "baz"
# get the 2nd element
puts [lindex $mylist 1]
# set the 3rd element to "Hello World"
lset mylist 2 "Hello World"
```

Comment: i just want this thing work in for loop with index...as $mylist $i how is this possible..i am using 50 node in ns2

Comment: It just works. Just don't use `global node(1) node(2)`, use `global node` and access it with `$node($i)` (when you use arrays).

Comment: Using numbers with keys is fine; it's a case that Tcl's hash function is actually tuned to handle very well.

Comment: Intresting. Does that applies to dicts as well @DonalFellows?